# how to change .immediate.types.apps to dynamic text

Tags: javascript, mongodb

this code is working, but i need the $push query field to be dynamin like this 
generalrecommendations[req.body.term].types.apps please help. 
        here is my mongodb database:

```
       "generalrecommendations" : {
            "immediate" : {
                "types" : {
                    "apps" : [
                        "1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    and here is my code:




db.collection('colleges').update(
   { '_id': new ObjectId(req.body.college) },
{
     $push:{ "generalrecommendations.immediate.types.apps": temp2[key1][i] } 

 }, function (err, result) {
})
```

finds the id and     appends new item to exixting array. here immediate is hardcoded but now i need to change it to dynamic like this req.body.term

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to make the query field dynamic you need to use [] operators while entering your query Field. Lets say your

`req.body.term = immediate`;

then instead of

`$push:{ "generalrecommendations.immediate.types.apps": temp2[key1][i] }`

use

`$push:{ ["generalrecommendations"+ req.body.term +"types.apps"]: temp2[key1][i] }`

adding [] to your query field will make it dynamic.